# how to keep the scrollbar to the right in a power bi chart

Tags: powerbi

I currently have this graphic

[image]

but to go to the information of the last weeks, I have to slide the scrollbar to the right.

[image]

Then I keep it this way. but when I view it on the web, it returns to the left side.

Will there be any way to always stay on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature for your problem. You have to find another way.

- Change the displayed days (from 51 to 28). So 51 is on the left side
- With filters
- Using drilldown
- Bigger chart length

Answer (score 0):

@Strawberryshrub is right, there isn't a setting for what you ask. (it has been proposed on [PowerBI Ideas](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9558120-line-chart-scroll-aligned-right-for-dates) though)

I've got some additional workarounds

- **Sort Order** - use a descending sort order, so the most recent data will be visible without scrolling
- **Continuous Axis** - set the X-Axis from "categorical" to "continuous", the axis will be compressed and all the values will be visible without any scroll bar
- **Filter Top N** - In the chart itself filter the top N weeks/days to show less values and avoid the scrollbar
- **Focus Mode** - View the visual in "focus mode" (on the top right when you hover it), this will put it in fullscreen